# I am trying to create one graph using plotly but keep on getting this error Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots)

Tags: r, graph, shiny, plotly

I am trying to create one graph using plotly but keep on getting this error. Any help is appreciated

> Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) :    Evaluation error: argument
>   "value" is missing, with no default.

Code looks like this:

```
plot_ly(Graph_lost, x = ~Month_Year, y = ~Final_Series_AfterLost,type='scatter',mode='lines',name='Actual')
```

where Graph_lost is a data frame with 2 columns one concat of month and year, and another unit of sales.

Comment: The following works fine for me: `library(plotly);
Graph_lost = data.frame(Month_Year=c(1,2,3), Final_Series_AfterLost = c(4,5,6));
plot_ly(Graph_lost, x = ~Month_Year, y = ~Final_Series_AfterLost,type='scatter',mode='lines',name='Actual')
`

Comment: please supply some test data. For example the out put of `dput(Graph_lost)`

Comment: same problem here:  

```> df <- data.frame (x=c(1,2,3), y=c(1,2,3))  
> plot_ly(df, x=~x, y=~y, type="scatter", mode="lines")
Error in arrange_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: `as_dictionary()` is defunct as of rlang 0.3.0.
Please use `as_data_pronoun()` instead.
```